# Add padding to svg background element in CSS

Tags: css, svg

In CSS, I am looking for a way to add space between an svg and the div element containing it.

Now, the svg is included in the `background` attribute with `no-repeat`, which causes it to appear cramped inside of the div container.

Is there a trick or workaround to uniformly add space so that there is padding **between** the svg and the container?

[image]

```
#rack-button {
  position: absolute;
   background: url('simple_rack.svg') no-repeat top left;
   background-size: contain;
   display: inline-block;
  background-color:white;
  width:  34px;
  height: 34px;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #B8B8B8;
}
```

Comment: Add actual padding, and then try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Comment: _“which causes it to appear cramped inside of the div container”_ - that’s actually more due to `background-size: contain` ... If your icons are all square, then you could also simply specify a background-size in percent.

Comment: Thanks, they are square, could you provide an example?

Comment: Try `background-size: 90% auto;` or something like that ... If you need more help, then please create a [mcve] first (so that not everyone else has to go and create a workable example themselves.)